# Deletion of a node from a BST

Tags: algorithms, binary-search-trees

Placed exactly the code and the explanation of the book : [Introduction to Algorithms Third Edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262530910/)

> In order to move subtrees around within the binary search tree, we
> define a subroutine TRANSPLANT, which replaces one subtree as a child
> of its parent with another subtree. When TRANSPLANT replaces the
> subtree rooted at node u with the subtree rooted at node , node u’s
> parent becomes node ’s parent, and u’s parent ends up having  as its
> appropriate child.

```
TRANSPLANT(T, u, v)
1 if u.p == NIL
2     T.root = v
3 elseif u == u.p.left
4     u.p.left = v
5 else u.p.right = v
6 if v!= NIL
7     v.p = u.p
```

As written in the book at the end of this procedure "TRANSPLANT replaces the subtree rooted at node u with the subtree rooted at node , node u’s parent becomes node ’s parent, and u’s parent ends up having as its appropriate child." . But I add, correct me if I'm wrong, the pointers that node u has to its left child , right child and parent are still valid and can be reused. Basically TRANSPLANT, only arranges the references between the parent of the u node that we want to remove and the v node that we want to replace. That is, the parent of u will have as its left or right child, depending on the case, the node v and the node v will have as its parent the parent of u. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now I report the code of the procedure for eliminating a node that uses the TRANSPLANT(T, u, v) code:

```
TREE-DELETE(T, z)
1 if z.left == NIL
2     TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.right)
3 elseif z.right == NIL
4     TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.left)
5 else y = TREE-MINIMUM(z.right)
6     if y.p != z
7         TRANSPLANT(T, y, y.right)
8         y.right= z.right
9         y.right.p = y
10    TRANSPLANT(T, z, y)
11    y.left = z.left
12    y.left.p = y
```

To be even clearer I carry the image that describes the entire procedure.

[image]

My doubts concern line 9 and line 12 of the TREE-DELETE(T, z) code.since, after the TRANSPLANT(T, y, y.right) of line 7, as written before we still have that node y points to its left and right child (furthermore the left child of y is always NIL when z has a left child and a right child. Exercise 12.2-5 of the book). So y.right = x and y.right.p is node y, I don't understand the meaning of the assignment made in line 9. I have the same doubts on line 12, just for exercise 12.2-5 we have that, when z has a left child and a right child, and if we enter the else in line 5 we are in this condition we have that y.left = NIL , so what's the point of y.left.p = y.

the code that would be natural for me to write would be this:

```
TREE-DELETE(T, z)
1 if z.left == NIL
2     TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.right)
3 elseif z.right == NIL
4     TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.left)
5 else y = TREE-MINIMUM(z.right)
6     if y.p != z
7         TRANSPLANT(T, y, y.right)
8         y.right= z.right
9    TRANSPLANT(T, z, y)
10    y.left = z.left
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The extra assignments adjust some parent links, don't they ?

Comment: (`What am I doing wrong?` You don't present the rendition of `TREE-DELETE(T, z)` *line 9 and line 12* refer to.)

Comment: I'm guessing that the title should have "from" in it, rather than "form".